# Looping Random Forest with different training sets

Tags: r, loops, classification, random-forest

I'm trying to loop Random Forest from the RStoolbox for different training sets and not for different images. The goal is to see how the quality of the training data influences the results of a landcover classification. 'training_data' is a list of lots of SpatialPolygonDataFrames and I want to run random forest for every training set.

```
 ###Loop for classification Random Forest

        model <- "rf" 

        for (i in training_data) {

          set.seed(10),
          RandomForest <- superClass(img=landsat_scene,
                        trainData = i, responseCol = "Classname",
                        model = 'rf', kfold=10, mode="classification",verbose = TRUE)
          saveRSTBX(RandomForest,filename=paste("04_analysis/",i,model,sep=""))
          writeRaster(RandomForest$map, filename=paste("04_analysis/",i,model,".tif",
                      sep=""), format='GTiff', datatype='INT1U', overwrite=TRUE)
          plot(RandomForest$map)
        }
```

Unfortunately, it only works for the first training set. What am I doing wrong? :/

Comment: What flaw I've noticed already: you're using `i` as a name for a file, this looks suspicious, because `i` is a `SpatialPolygonDataFrames`. Are there any errors arise? Can you provide an example and short input (probably 2-3 short, artificial items).

Comment: Please explain *it only works for the first training set*. What works? All the `superClass`, `saveRSTBX`, `writeRaster`, `plot` methods?

Comment: `i` should call every `SpatialPolygonDataFrame` to action. I tried the same method for `img=` with 3 different RapidEye images in a list and it worked, but I think the approach needs to be different for Polygons. How can I address the training sets for the loop?

Comment: And _it only works for the first training set_ means: `superClass`,`saveRSTBX`etc. worked, but only once, so for one set of training data. This is exactly my problem.. I need a method to loop through all of them! Thanks for your efforts guys!

Comment: @JuliaSauerbrey Then you should use indexing: `for(i in 1:length(training_data))` and inside the loop assign `training_data[i]` to some training variable.